# How to style individual slots in a Vaadin GridLayout?

Tags: sass, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I want to have a border on some of the slots in my GridLayout.
If I set the border on the element within the slot (with the help of a style name), the border is not drawn all the way.

How can I access the enclosing gridlayout-slot, so that every other slot has a border?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you put a CssLayout in the GridLayout and style that like this:

```
final GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, 2);
// the size of the grid layout has to be defined, otherwise you can't place a relatively sized component inside it
gridLayout.setHeight("400px"); // example height
gridLayout.setWidth("100%"); // example width

final CssLayout border = new CssLayout();
border.setStyleName("myCellStyle");
// make the layout fill the whole slot
border.setSizeFull();
// wrap your content with that border layout
border.addComponent(new Label("forth"));
gridLayout.addComponents(
            new Label("first"), 
            new Label("second"),
            new Label("third"),
            border);
```

In your mytheme.scss write your border style:

```
.myCellStyle {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```